# Undefined function despite being defined in imported .proto file

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-go

I have 2 `.proto` files in the same directory such that `second.proto` is dependent on `first.proto`

**second.proto**

```
import "first.proto"

enum ThingINeed {
    ...something
}
```

I have no problem running these commands:

```
$ protoc --go_out=generatedsources/first -I. first.proto
$ protoc --go_out=generatedsources/second -I. second.proto
```

so the directory structure looks something like

```
 src
    |-first.proto
    |-second.proto
    |-generatedsources
         |-first
              |-first.pb.go
         |-second
              |-second.pb.go
```

My problem is that when I run

```
$ cd generatedsources/second
$ go build second.pb.go
```

I receive a

> *./second.pb.go: Undefined: ThingINeed*

since `second.pb.go` uses `ThingINeed` from `first.pb.go` (seen in `first.proto` as well)

I notice that `second.pb.go` doesn't have an `import . "generatedsources/first"` line in it. When I put it in manually, it works just fine. But I'm not supposed to edit these `.pb.go` files, so was wondering how to fix this. I also would prefer not to edit these `.proto` files.

Comment: What are the package names of those proto files? You might need to add `option go_package="pkgname";` to those so they can refer to the correct packages

Comment: ahh that helps. I didn't have that option. I made sure they all were in the same package and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do the opposite when organizing your files. That is, have one `generatedsources` directory and as many source directories for the .proto files as you'd like. Save all the `.pb.go` files in the same location and they will "find each other" automatically.

This can be achieved using the `--go_out=...` parameter. As per your example:

```
$ protoc --go_out=generatedsources -I. first.proto
$ protoc --go_out=generatedsources -I. second.proto
```

And if you want to group the `.proto` files differently, you can do that:

```
$ protoc --go_out=generatedsources -I. set1/first.proto
$ protoc --go_out=generatedsources -I. set1/second.proto
$ protoc --go_out=generatedsources -I. set2/third.proto
$ protoc --go_out=generatedsources -I. set2/forth.proto
```

The files all need to have different filenames, though. That's generally a good idea anyway.

---

*References:*

- [Proposal: Overloading option go_package to indicate Go import path](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/139)
- [proto files in another directory best practices question](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/230)